# How can one simplify $\sum_{n=1}^8\frac{\sin10n^\circ}{\cos5^\circ\cos10^\circ\cos20^\circ}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have trouble solving the following question:

> Consider the following expression:
> $$\sum_{n=1}^8\frac{\sin10n^\circ}{\cos5^\circ\cos10^\circ\cos20^\circ}$$
> The value of the above expression can be fully simplified into the form $a\sqrt b$. What is $a+b$?

I know that $$\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\right)$$
but I'm not too sure what pairs of $\sin$ I should apply it on, or if this is even the right approach to this problem. Could someone give me hints for solving this problem(Am I on the right track)?

Comment: The index $n$ is not used in your summation. Is it supposed to be used?

Comment: Do you mean $n$ where you have $x?$

Comment: Judging by the tags used and your profile page, this may not be appropriate, but my first instinct is that you should use complex numbers. The geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^8 e^{in\pi/18}$ has real part $\sum_{i=1}^8 \sin(10n^\circ)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
Use the formula that, $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin(a+rh) = \frac{\sin(\frac{nh}{2})\sin(a+(n-1)\frac{h}{2})}{\sin(\frac{h}{2})}$

so, Let $$P = \sum_{n=1}^{8}\frac{\sin(10n^\circ)}{\cos(5^\circ)\cos(10^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cos(5^\circ)\cos(10^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)}\sum_{n=1}^{8}\sin(10n^\circ)$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cos(5^\circ)\cos(10^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)}\cdot\frac{\sin(\frac{8\cdot10}{2})\sin(10+7\cdot\frac{10}{2})}{\sin(\frac{10}{2})}$$
$$=\frac{\sin(40^\circ)\sin(45^\circ)}{\cos(5^\circ)\cos(10^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)\sin(5^\circ)}$$
$$=2\cdot\frac{\sin(40^\circ)\sin(45^\circ)}{2\cos(5^\circ)\sin(5^\circ)\cos(10^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)}$$
$$=4\cdot\frac{\sin(40^\circ)\sin(45^\circ)}{2\sin(10^\circ)\cos(10^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)}$$
$$=8\cdot\frac{\sin(40^\circ)\sin(45^\circ)}{2\sin(20^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)}$$
$$=8\frac{\sin(40^\circ)\sin(45^\circ)}{\sin(40^\circ)}$$
$$P=8\sin(45^\circ)$$

So, $P=4\cdot\sqrt{2}$,
therefore $a = 4$ & $b=2$, so $a+b=6$

I hope this was helpful, :)

Comment: This was helpful but, because I'm not too experienced in trigonometry, I have no idea how I would reduce something like $8\cos20^\circ$ into the form $a\sqrt b$. Could you help me on that as well? Thanks.

Comment: @AidenChow, There were some mistakes, now iIve corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My answer key is saying the answer is $6$, but it's only because $\frac 8{\sqrt2}=4\sqrt2\implies a+b=4+2=6$.

Comment: @AidenChow, Yes that is right, it will be 6

Comment: Also near the end, I think you meant to write $8\frac{\sin40^\circ\sin45^\circ}{\color{red}{\sin40^\circ}}$ instead of $8\frac{\sin40^\circ\sin45^\circ}{\cos40^\circ}$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Could you also tell me where I can find a proof of the formula you introduced at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: @AidenChow, yes, and you just search "sine series summation" In google, and you can find out the proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123014/discussion-between-pranjal-and-aiden-chow).

Answer (score 2):

Proof:

$$\begin{align}
S&= \sum_{n=1}^{n}\sin(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)
\\S\cdot2\sin\frac\beta2&=\sum_{n=1}^{n}\sin(\alpha+(n-1)\beta)\cdot2\sin\frac\beta2
\\S\cdot2\sin\frac\beta2&=\sum_{n=1}^{n}\cos\left(\alpha+\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\beta\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{n}\cos\left(\alpha+\left(n-\frac{3}{2}\right)\beta\right)
\\S\cdot2\sin\frac\beta2&=\cos\left(\alpha+(n-1)\frac{\beta}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\alpha-\frac{\beta}{2}\right)
\\S\cdot2\sin\frac\beta2&=2\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{(n-1)\beta}{2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{n\cdot\beta}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$

---

Hope this proof is understandable to you. Thanks

Comment: This is brilliant, very good, well done. +1 One very nice and small thing, you can do `\sin` to get $\sin$ instead of $sin$, the same with $\cos$ and so on.

Comment: Just clarifying, are the periods supposed to indicate multiplication? If so, you can use `\cdot`.

Comment: Ok, next time I will include both things.